# How is cloud height measured?

Tags: weather, altitude

In general, cloud height is measured from ground or AMSL (above mean sea level)?

If they measure from AMSL, how are low level clouds' height measured in higher terrain?

Answer (score 1):

[Cloud ceiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceiling_(cloud)) is measured from ground:

> height of the base of the lowest clouds ... that cover more than half
>   of the sky ... relative to the ground

[Cloud base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_base) is measured from sea level:

> ... the lowest altitude of the visible portion of the cloud. It is
>   traditionally expressed either in m or feet above mean sea level